# choose the middle in merge sort

Tags: python-3.x, mergesort

I was trying to complete a merge sort in Python. I found when I use `middle = (len(x)-1)//2`, the right part was in infinity loop and never reached the base case, but if I changed m`iddle = len(x)//2`, it worked normally. So why?
[image: python merge sort]

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the question, instead of linking to a screenshot. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The middle is actually `(len(x)+1)//2`.

Comment: I think using (len(x)+1)//2 is the same to len(x)//2 considering the index is from 0. And it doesn't matter if you choose the position a little left or right.

Comment: Actually, middle = (start + end)//2 in maths. The start in my list is 0 and the end is len(x)-1, so middle = (len(x)-1)//2. But why the right was in infinity loop if I did so?

Answer (score 0):

The solution does lie in the `middle` variable. After abit of experimenting I found that using `middle = len(alist)//2` fixes the whole program. Despite this not being technically mathematical, it does seem to work.

You could also increase efficiency by replacing the if and else at the start of the `mergesort()` function with a simple `if len(alist) > 1:` and then return `alist` at the end of the function, rather than at the end of each if and else, if that makes sense. (This would also mean you can just replace the `com` variable with `alist`).

For reference, heres my code (some variables are renamed):

```
from random import shuffle

###  INIT  ###
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
shuffle(arr)
print("Starting List:  " + str(arr))

###  SORT   ###
# Merge
def merge(left,right):
    sorted = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            sorted.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            sorted.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    
    sorted += right[j:]
    sorted += left[i:]
    return sorted


# Decomposition
def sort(arr):
    #print(arr)
    if len(arr) > 1:
        middle = len(arr)//2
        left = sort(arr[:middle])
        right = sort(arr[middle:])
        arr = merge(left, right)
    return arr

arr = sort(arr)
print("Ending List:    " + str(arr))
```